# Implementation of PSK modulation/demodulation

Tags: arduino, adc, modulation, bpsk

I want to implement a BPSK modulation/demodulation using a microcontroller (Arduino Due). The carrier signal should be at 1-50 MHz and the information rate at 300 KHz. For the sender part I would implement it using two DDS driven by one oscillators. But I cannot figure out how to do this at the receiver side. I found out that the ADC's sample rate of the Due is limited to 1 MHz and too low for sampling the received signal. So does this mean that I have to preprocess the signal analogously?

Comment: Undersampling demodulation springs to mind. Try looking at software radio receivers.

Answer (score 1):

Partially you question is answered in [this topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132642/how-to-get-bpsk-data-from-i-q-signal). Probably you need analogue carrier recovery circuit, for example Costas loop-based circuit. Good theoretical review of BPSK Costas loops is given in [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04288).